# Date-Time format f for en-GB, breaking change from .NET to .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Do this in .NET 4.7.2:

```
Trace.WriteLine(
    new DateTime(2023, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).ToString(
        "f",
        CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")));
```

And you get:

```
03 February 2023 04:05
```

Do it in .NET 6.0, and you get:

```
Friday, 3 February 2023 04:05
```

I can't see that this is a documented breaking change, so what's going on? A custom format string gets over the problem in my own code, but I have an application that compiles code on the fly based on, among other things, user-selected configuration including date-time formats. When the user gets an upgrade of the product that uses .NET 6.0 instead of .NET 4.7.2 and they have configurations that specify "f" as the format, they are going to get duff output.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/5.0/icu-globalization-api

Comment: It's annoying as heck, I have one server where (despite configuring everything I can think of) an ASP.NET Core web app thinks money has three decimals. So it's `N2` all the way.

Comment: Looking at the link @CodeCaster added there seems to be a way to revert to the old behaviour in .NET 5+. Although I'm sure they may have already tried that with limited results by the sound of it!